# Android ListView Multiple checkboxes

Tags: android

I've a listView inside a FrameLayout Activity (not list Activity).

I can listen to clicks using `checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)`

How do I determine which checkbox was clicked? I dont get any index.

ps `OnListItemClicked` is out of scope since I'm not using `ListActivity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement onListItemClickListener(). Iterate all the listview items and check each item (each item child view).

```
for(int i = 0; i  <= listView.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++)
    {
        if(listView.getChildAt(i)!= null)
        { 
            if(((CheckBox)listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkbox)).isChecked())
            {  
          //do something
             }else { //do something else}

        }
    }
```

or you can check in `getView()` method if the item checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: if(((CheckBox)listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkbox)).isChecked())


you can simplify this to
View parentView = listView.getChildAt(i);
CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox)parentView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
if(chkbox.isChecked())

Comment: I meant I wouldn't want to loop over all the children, There should be a better way to do it.

Comment: There is ofcourse,in `getView()` method in your Adapter, there you can check.

Answer (score 1):

do something like this

```
Vector vect = new Vector();
lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, item));
    lv1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lv1.setClickable(true);
    lv1.setScrollingCacheEnabled(true); 
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(deleteclicklistener);


private OnItemClickListener deleteclicklistener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
            long id) {
        if(vect.contains(position))
        {
            vect.removeElement(position);
        }else
        {
            vect.addElement(position);
        }
    }
};
```

I think this should solve your problem

Comment: Line item should be separately clickable. Setting clickable to True makes checkbox + line item one clickable thing.

Answer (score 0):

ListView still has a setOnListItemClickedListener() method you can just create your listener as an object and pass it in, rather than implementing it on your Activities context.

Edit: Yes it does, it gets inherited from AdapterView.

Go to [ListView docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) scroll down to the Inherited methods section and click the arrow to the left of AdapterView you'll find setOnItemClickListener(). I have used it in code before I assure that it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `listView1.getCheckedItemPosition()`. You could also try doing this:

```
private int checkedItemPosition;

listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View selectedItem, int position, long itemId)
    {
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)selectedItem.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        if (checkbox.isChecked())
        {
            checkedItemPosition = position;
        }
    }
});
```